# xdotool - tab key

Tags: chromium, xdotool, kiosk

I just found out `xdotool`, so sorry if I ask basic questions, but I can't find the answer.

**How can I simulate the tab key?**

On a Raspberry, I start chromium in kiosk mode on an application that requires a login. I therefore want to enter the data via `xdotool` and confirm.

I currently do this activity every 10 minutes, then I would like to understand if there is also the possibility to set it every 5 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Please also limit to a single question at a time. You currently have 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering only the main part of your question

> How can I simulate the tab key?

You can do it with the command

```
xdotool key Tab
```

It is `Tab` and not `tab` or `TAB`.

Comment: I feel stupid. Thank you for the tip!